# Complicated Epsilon Proof

Tags: proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I've been banging my head against the table with this question.

$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^2 +3x}{x+2}
$$
 It just doesnt want to simplify

Here's what I have so far for the smaller:

$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{-2}{x+2}
$$

$$ \frac{2|{x-a}|}{|a+2|}* \frac{1}{|x+2|} $$

So if I bound $$|x-a|<\delta<1$$ can I then say that $$a-1<x<a+1$$ which means that $$\frac{1}{|x+2|} = \frac{1}{|a+1|} or \frac{1}{|a+3|}$$ and then find the min delta with the two of those?

In my class we usually do the triangle inequality so I'm not sure if this works

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far?

Comment: does $a$ have any restrictions? such as $a \neq -2$

Comment: It's probably worth noting that $\frac {x^2 +3x}{x+2}=\frac {x^2 +2x+x+2-2}{x+2}=\frac {x(x +2)+(x+2)-2}{x+2}=x+1-\frac {2}{x+2}$

Comment: a=/= -2 yes sorry.  I'm still having trouble with the simplification. I get |x-a|-|2/(a+2)|-|2/(x+2)| and I dont know where to go from there

Comment: something you can do is prove separately that  $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{-2}{x+2} = \frac{-2}{a+2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to a} x = a$$
$$\lim_{1\to a} 1 = 1$$        and then, you can pick the minimum of those deltas(you found in each proof) and that will work

Comment: Ok I'll try that